# Why can't I befriend a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

When researching an answer to a question (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000908/is-it-possible-to-forbid-deriving-from-a-class-at-compile-time/1000944#1000944)) I tried to do the following:

```
template <class T>
class friendly {
    friend class T;
};

friendly<string> howdy;
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

> error: template parameter "T" may not be used in an
>             elaborated type specifier
>             friend class T;

From what I can understand from my good friend Google this is so that I won't accidentally try to instantiate `friendly<int>` but why should this be an error when compiling the template? Should't it be an error when instantiating the template with an invalid type (such as had I written `int f() { return T::foo(); }`)

Comment: How to Make Friends and Influence Parameters.

Comment: Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392120/why-cant-i-declare-a-friend-through-a-typedef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more googleling brought up **Extended `friend` Declarations** [(PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1791.pdf) for [C++0x](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2565.html).

This document contains the following:

```
template <typename T> class R {
    friend T;
};
R<C> rc; // class C is a friend of R<C>
R<int> ri; // OK: “friend int;” is ignored
```

Which goes even further than what I thought (ignoring illegal `friend` decelerations rather than failing during instantiation). So I guess the answer is that there isn't a good reason and it's being rectified.

Answer (score 3):

Section 7.1.5.3 of the standard explicitly describes this as an example of an illformed elaborated type specifier.

A discussion about the subject can be found [here](http://www.cpptalk.net/may-a-template-argument-be-a-friends-of-the-template-class-vt41742.html).

Comment: +1, good find. I remember butting up against this one time. I don't know why it's verboten though -- maybe it caused difficulties for compiler implementors?

Comment: Don't question the bible, son.

Comment: I had a look at the referenced thread and apart from pointing out that it's illegal there is no insight as to why (which is what I'm after in this question).

Comment: You're right. I don't know what the rationale is either. But that goes for a lot of things in a language designed by committee.