# Not able to befriend typedefs: any particular reason?

Tags: c++, typedef, c++11, friend

```
struct A {};
typedef A B;

struct C { friend struct B; };
```

GCC 4.7.0 20110427 tells me `error: using typedef-name 'B' after 'struct'`.

So far, this seems pretty self-explanatory; after all, my example code is trying to declare-and-friend a `struct` called B, which is in fact not a `struct-key`.

However, I have to write `friend struct A;` if `A` is in fact a complex, long-winded mess of template metahackery, this is not desirable.

Am I missing something, or can we in fact *not* `friend` types through type aliases? If not, is there any particular reason or is it just a quirk of the language?

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392120/why-cant-i-declare-a-friend-through-a-typedef) brought up the issue before, but is dated and makes assertions on the matter regarding C++0x that don't appear to be true. *This question instead regards the C++0x FDIS.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656948/a-class-key-must-be-declared-when-declaring-a-friend/657113#657113 might be related.

Comment: Oh, hah... this was me. Lol....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can befriend arbitrary types (for non-class types, the friend declaration will be ignored), but then you shall omit `struct`:

```
struct A {};
typedef A B;

struct C { 
  friend B; // equivalent: friend struct A;
            // equivalent: friend A;

  friend int; // ignored
};
```

Comment: Perhaps GCC 4.7.0 and [GCC 4.5.1](http://www.ideone.com/3Dk5j) don't support this yet?

Comment: @Tomalak yes, they don't support this.

Comment: Ah yes, Clang 2.9 (trunk 126116) appears to support it.